# Read a .txt file memory efficient in Python

Tags: python, list, txt

I'm reading some .txt files as lists, using this method:

```py
with open('../Results/DIMP_1120.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1120 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))
with open('../Results/DIMP_1121.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1121 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))
with open('../Results/DIMP_1122.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1122 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))
```

But this is taking almost 10x the size of the file in the RAM memory.

Is there an efficient way to read it?

After that I'll append those lists and sort them.

```py
big_list = DIMP_1120 + DIMP_1121 + DIMP_1122

#Order all lists by *Sorter (Row_id2)
from operator import itemgetter
big_list= sorted(big_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

So I guess I need to bring all lists to memory at once.

Comment: Do you need it as a `list` all at once? If you can process it row by row it will only need the memory for a row at a time (well, two rows at a time given how Python iteration works, but close enough). Otherwise, yeah, the overhead of Python `str` is ~49 bytes a piece, plus the overhead of each `list` wrapper, so if most of the fields are short, the overhead relative to the data will be quite high.

Comment: Hey, thx for reply. Yes I need it all at once, because i'm appending to other lists and sorting all of them. Reading as Pickle instead of txt could help?

Comment: Pickling won't help much unless the underlying data can be stored using more memory efficient types (e.g. storing and restoring raw `int`). I added a note on how you might take advantage of that while still using `csv`, simply by performing the type conversions as you load.

Comment: "appending to other lists and sorting all of them" doesn't necessarily require reading all at once. We could help you better if we knew more details.

Comment: Can you show a few lines of the data? How many files do you have? How large is each file? What are you doing with the final big sorted list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can process the data a row at a time without storing each row, e.g.

```
for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"):
```

do that; it's the only way to *dramatically* reduce peak memory usage.

Otherwise, the best you can do is convert the row storage format from `list` to `tuple` as you read, which should save at least a little memory (more if `csv.reader` isn't truncating the overallocation `list` does by default), as `tuple`s don't overallocate, and they store data inline with the Python object header (without overallocation or additional allocator round-off overhead), while `list`'s header just adds a pointer to separately allocated memory (which overallocates and incurs twice the round-off overhead); for a dynamically allocated `list` of size 2 (e.g. in CPython 3.9 where unpacking generalizations behave like sequential appends, `[*(0, 1)]`), the container overhead can drop from 120 bytes to 56 bytes (possibly more, since allocator round-off error isn't visible to `sys.getsizeof`, and `list` pays it twice, `tuple` just once) just by converting to `tuple`, which can make a difference for millions of such rows. The most efficient means of converting it would be to change:

```
DIMP_1120 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))
```

to:

```
DIMP_1120 = list(map(tuple, csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")))
```

`map` operates lazily on Python 3, so each row would be read as a `list`, converted to a `tuple`, and stored in the outer `list` before the next was read; it wouldn't involve storing the whole input as `list`s and `tuple`s at the same time, even for a moment. If your underlying data has some fields that could be converted up-front to a more efficiently stored type (e.g. `int`), a `list` comprehension that both converts the fields and packs them as `tuple`s instead of `list`s could gain more, e.g. for four fields per row, the last three of which are logically `int`s, you could do:

```
DIMP_1120 = [(a, int(b), int(c), int(d)) for a, b, c, d in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")]
# If you might have some empty/missized rows you wish to ignore, an if check can discard
# wrong length lists; a nested "loop" over the single item can unpack after checking:
DIMP_1120 = [(a, int(b), int(c), int(d)) for lst in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
             if len(lst) == 4
             for a, b, c, d in (lst,)]
```

unpacking the `list`s from `csv.reader`, converting the relevant fields to `int`, and repacking as a `tuple`.

Side-note: Make sure to pass `newline=""` (the empty string) to your `open` call; the `csv` module requires this to properly handle newlines from different CSV dialects.

**Update:** Reading into separate `list`s, then concatenating, then sorting, boosts peak outer `list` overhead from being proportionate to number of rows to being proportionate to being ~2.66x times the number of rows (assuming all files are the same size). You can avoid that overhead by changing:

```
with open('../Results/DIMP_1120.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1120 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))  
with open('../Results/DIMP_1121.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1121 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))  
with open('../Results/DIMP_1122.txt', 'r') as f:
    DIMP_1122 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"))  

big_list = DIMP_1120 + DIMP_1121 + DIMP_1122

#Order all lists by *Sorter (Row_id2)
from operator import itemgetter
big_list= sorted(big_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

to:

```
from itertools import chain

with open('../Results/DIMP_1120.txt', 'r') as f1, \
     open('../Results/DIMP_1121.txt', 'r') as f2, \
     open('../Results/DIMP_1122.txt', 'r') as f3:
    
    ALL_DIMP = chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
                                   for f in (f1, f2, f3))
    big_list = sorted(map(tuple, ALL_DIMP), key=itemgetter(0))
```

Only one `list` is ever made (your original code had six `list`s; one for each input file, one for the concatenation of the first two files, one for the concatenation of all three files, and a new one for the sorted concatenation of all three files), containing all the data, and it's created sorted from the get-go.

I'll note that this may be something better done at the command line, at least on *NIX-like systems, where the `sort` command line utility knows how to sort huge files by field, with automatic spilling to disk to avoid storing too much in memory at once. It could be done in Python, but it would be uglier (unless there's some PyPI module for doing this I don't know about).

Comment: [little experiment](https://tio.run/##hYwxDgIhEEV7TjEdkBAaGxtPYixYmFUShcnMRHe9PK6bWNu@//6jVW@9HY7EY9QHdVbI8gwgqxjD/QUnsAkmyFBsFLpXdd4Q16ZuW3cvXlGlvrHPX@T979dwUbfFImMqyO5sU5hCDsVe/L/GGB8) of the overhead.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: There's still a non-linear growth pattern; try it with `'a,b,c,d,e'` and the memory usage for the `csv.reader`'s output jumps from 88 bytes of overhead to 120 (`tuple`ing then drops it back to 80). Looks like a difference in how `split` is overallocating (I accidentally chose an example that overallocates more than default `list` building; when no `maxsplit` provided, it reserves space for 12 items up front and doesn't trim at the end). So conversion to `tuple` can save memory, but not as much as my toy comparison indicated.

Comment: Thanks. This improved memory usage in almost 30%.

Comment: I updated my example to avoid the `.split` extra-overallocation (while also, intentionally, showing a best case scenario, where the `list` overhead is more than twice the `tuple` overhead; in practice, all `tuple` can *guarantee* is that `tuple(somelist)` will consume at least 16 fewer bytes than calling `list(somelist)`, which in CPython 3.9 will not include any overallocation overhead on the copy of `somelist` (it sizes precisely to the elements given). `tuple` still saves 16 bytes (plus allocator round-off loss) by avoiding storing a pointer and a separate `ssize_t` capacity field.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the data to a `list` means you are loading and saving all lines to memory. What you can do instead is iterate over the lines one by one by iterating over the [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) instead, which as documented:

> #### csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
>
> Return a reader object which **will iterate over lines in the given csvfile**. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and **returns a string each time its **next**() method is called**... Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

```
with open('../Results/DIMP_1120.txt', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")):
        # Process the current line
```

The disadvantage of this is you only have access to 1 line at a time. But I believe if you don't want to load everything to memory at once, this might be the only way. You just need to redesign your logic to process everything that needs to be done per line.

Comment: Hey, thx for reply. Yes I need it all at once, because i'm appending to other lists and sorting all of them. Reading as Pickle instead of txt could help?